# Meteor - router doesn't show layoutTemplate

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a very simple function that checks wether user is logged in and else send him to the signup page.

```
var requireLogin = function() { 
    if (! Meteor.user()) {
        this.render('signUpForm', {
            path: '/signup',
            layoutTemplate: 'signup'
        }); 
    } 
    // else if () {
    //  this.render('listProfiles'); 
    // } 
    else {
        this.next(); 
    }
};
```

this is the layoutTemplate (as simple as can be I believe) :

```
<template name="signup">
    <div class="signup-page">
        <div class="container">
            {{> yield}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

I can't use the layoutTemplate with .render?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using Iron Router.

As far as I know, you can't pass the layout template into the render function.

The easiest way get around this would be to use Router config:

```
// router.js
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'signup'
});
```

Then in your js:

```
if (! Meteor.user()) {
    this.render('signUpForm');
}
```

Comment: I see, now I just override the default layoutTemplate in other router logic. Not sure if this is the best way to fix it, but it'll do for now:) thx!

edit: and yea i do use iron router!

Comment: If you are using different layouts, you could set up the sign up router in your router file and assign the layout template in that and then use Router.go() in your js.